# use of indefinite article 'a'

Tags: articles

Why in the sentence “People form far too complex a system to enable reliable mathematical predictions of outcomes” the indefinite article ‘a’ is not before ‘far’ or ‘complex’?

Answer (score 1):

This sentence is an example of this structure:

*[ "too" + adjective + "a" + noun ]*

It has the meaning of *a noun that is/was too adjective*.

So, in our case here, the sentence could be rephrased:

> People form **a system that is far too complex** to enable reliable mathematical predictions of outcomes

In the original, with one subordinate clause fewer, the sentence is easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Because the article comes before the noun in this particular English construction.

Consider the sentence:

> He was far too kind a man to turn them away.

It means that he was the sort of man who is too kind to do something like that.

Your sentence means "People form a system which is far too complex to..."